# Presenting an alert

Tags: xcode, alert, swiftui

I running SwiftUI with Xcode 11 Beat 5, and I wish to add an Alert to show the user when a Button is Tapped.

I am having problems though.

```
HStack{
    Text("Inverted V")
      .font(.largeTitle)
      .fontWeight(.bold)
      .foregroundColor(Color.black)
    Spacer()
    Button(action: {

    }, label: {
      Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
      .resizable()
      .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
      .foregroundColor(.red)

    }).onTapGesture {
      print("Hello Print")

  }}
```

Can someone help with the code needed? Do I place it within the onTapGesture brackets?

I have a @State var showingAlert = false

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help and suggestions however I'm not sure if that will help me... I am using a TapGesture as it's in a List... I was told at this time a button does not work, but selects the entire line. So the TapGesture is working fine.. I am just not sure how to show an alert when the TapGesture is tapped. Thank you.. Hope that makes sense.. I'm a newby.

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like the code below. If you are using onTapGesture you don't need a Button.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingAlert: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            Text("Inverted V")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            Spacer()

            Image(systemName: "questionmark.circle.fill")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .onTapGesture {
                    print("Hello Print")
                    self.showingAlert = true
            }
        }.alert(isPresented: $showingAlert, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text("Error Reason"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
        })
    }
}
```